# Codeigniter limit certain page elements to profile owner

Tags: function, codeigniter

I want to limit access to certain elements of a user's profile so that only the user can see them and not other logged in users. So far the is_logged_in function (see below) works fine, now I need to refine it so that it is limited to a specific user that is logged in.

I'm already including a user_id variable in my session data, so that's available for use.

```
function is_logged_in()
{
    $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
    if($is_logged_in)
    {   
        $this->index();
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('fooview');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to know the user_id of the profile you are viewing, lets assume in your controller you have it as `$user_id`.

in your controller you can do `$is_owner = $this->session->userdata('user_id') == $user_id ? true : false;`

then pass it to your view as e.g. `$is_owner`.

then in your view simply have

```
if($is_owner){
  //show stuff
} else {
  //message saying stuff is private!
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks, this mostly makes sense to me. You're saying define $is_owner as the user_id from the session data and then $is_owner should equal the $user_id as defined in the profile controller--is that correct? The only thing I don't understand the true/false bit after the $is_owner statement.